# Can someone tell me what font is used here in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updated the Visual Studio Code to v1.37.0 and really liked the font used in the Release Notes.

[image: Release Notes]

Does anyone know what font is used in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I got this from setting  :

`Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace`

Comment: I tried it and its not the same font as shown in the screenshot